# How i get the occurrence of a sentence with google ngram viewer and python?

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

short backround: i try to enhance the spelling corrector by [Peter Norvig](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) in python. In this sense i need the occurrence of a sentence (up to 3-4 words)... The [Ngram viewer from Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams) would help me a lot but i don't know how i get the value with an API or something else.

pseudocode:

```
# Sentence without meaning but word for word correct.
>> occurrence("were are you")
0.0000000978

# Sentence that makes sense
>> occurrence("where are you")
0.000148

# Then my method should return the sentence with the highest value. (But thats not the problem)
```

sorry for my english :-D
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They actually have an undocumented api.

```
import requests
import json

term = "where are you"
url =f"https://books.google.com/ngrams/json?content={term}&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3"
resp = requests.get(url)
if resp.ok:
  results = json.loads(resp.content)
```

`results[0]['timeseries']` has the frequencies you need:

```
[2.854326695000964e-07,
 3.4926038665616944e-07,
 3.3916604043800663e-07,
 ...]
```

Source: https://jameshfisher.com/2018/11/25/google-ngram-api/

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 there is [NGRAMS](https://ngrams.dev) which is a search engine and REST API for the Google Books Ngram Dataset v3. You can accomplish your task with a single request:

```bash
curl -G https://api.ngrams.dev/eng/search \
--data-urlencode query='"were are you" / "where are you"' \
-d flags=cs
```

The query `"were are you" / "where are you"` asks to look up both `were are you` and `where are you` in the English corpus. `flags=cs` triggers a case-sensitive search. By default NGRAMS is case-insensitive.

**Output**

```json
{
  "queryTokens": [
    { "text": "\"were are you\"", "type": "TERM_GROUP" },
    { "text": "/", "type": "SLASH" },
    { "text": "\"where are you\"", "type": "TERM_GROUP" }
  ],
  "ngrams": [
    {
      "id": "b27a70f8e4b27baddd382ab96a986569",
      "absTotalMatchCount": 1015443,
      "relTotalMatchCount": 5.083529835293575e-7,
      "tokens": [
        { "text": "where", "type": "TERM" },
        { "text": "are", "type": "TERM" },
        { "text": "you", "type": "TERM" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "36a5fb73ab627ac0a0c1b5559627cb39",
      "absTotalMatchCount": 655,
      "relTotalMatchCount": 3.2790733129454743e-10,
      "tokens": [
        { "text": "were", "type": "TERM" },
        { "text": "are", "type": "TERM" },
        { "text": "you", "type": "TERM" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `relTotalMatchCount` property is the frequency you are looking for.